# HTML в webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser, img

Как при нажатии на кнопки отображать определённые тэги сразу в webbrowser s winforms?

Были попытки каждое нажатие кнопок загружать документ с помощью Navigate,  искать по циклу определённые тэги и добавлять на webbrowser с помощью innerhtml, но при нажатии кнопки выводит сам документ, а при повторном нажатии только то, что нужно. И здесь возникла ещё одна проблема, дело в том, что при загрузки страницы картинки, находящиеся в той же папке отображались, а когда используется innerhtml, то эти картинки не отображаются.
Может найдутся какие-то советы, как решить эти вопросы?

Спасибо!

Comment: Думаю, что без добавления Вашего кода Вам вряд ли можно что то посоветовать. Попробуйте добавить код в Ваш вопрос - там есть кнопка редактирования

Comment: `WebBrowser` - это самая ужасная реализация браузера из всех возможных (привет IE), которая годится лишь для вывода простого HTML документа, без современных стилей, JS и прочего. Вы уверены, что именно его хотите использовать? А также, задайте себе вопрос "А точно мне нужен браузер в проекте? Может с этого сайта можно получить информацию без рендера всего содержимого?" И вот исходя из этого, у вас 3 варианта: Если вам браузер не нужен, то добро пожаловать в мир HTTP запросов. Если нужен, то 1. Страдать с `WebBrowser` 2. Найти ему современную замену (привет `webview2`).

Comment: А и да, если вы вовсе разрабатываете UI средствами Web, то вам нужен [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). Собственно, как видите, ваш вопрос можно понимать по-разному, из-за чего и ответ будет разный.

Comment: Чтобы динамически управлять контентом в браузере, используют css и javascript. И `WebBrowser` закопайте обратно, он давно умер, похоронен и разложился, вместо него есть `WebView2` или `CefCharp`.